# Does adding a function argument constitute an ABI change?

Tags: api, abi

The Wikipedia says that ABI is a set of conventions how functions are called, how arguments are passed or structures are aligned, ex. are arguments passed through stack or through registers: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface#Description

But then I read this description of what constitutes an ABI change inside of the "dpdk" project documentation, and they are saying that the change from "rte_foo()" to "rte_foo(uint8_t bar)" constitutes an ABI change: https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/contributing/abi_policy.html#abi-breakages

According to Wikipedia, adding an argument to a function is not an ABI change, but is rather an API change.

Are "dpdk" documentation authors confused about what ABI is? Or is Wikipedia description not adequate?

Comment: Would existing code run the same without being recompiled?  If not, then the ABI has changed.

Comment: @NateEldredge This could be an ABI or an API change.